# Facebook Graph API: photo_tag table issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm having a weird issue.
I'd like to (nevermind why) have FQL return a dictionary of all people tagged in all of a given users photos.

So I have

```
query 1 something like SELECT pid from photo_tag where subject = 123456
and then query 2 something like select pid, subject from photo_tag where pid in (select pid from #query1)
```

Weird thing is that the second query returns a way smaller dictionary than query1 (it should be bigger, because it returns subjects individually, so it should have multiple results per pid).

I wasn't sure why so I threw in a new query2 which just says this:

```
SELECT pid from photo_tag WHERE pid in (SELECT pid FROM #query1)
```

And even that returns a fraction of the original pids! What the second query is saying in this case should just be "show me all of the pids that are in those pids" but they don't all return?

Any ideas? Sorry if this was convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, FQL rarely returns all rows that satisfy a query. The number of results are limited usually at 25 or 50 lines by default. With your queries, you can get far fewer results than that because Facebook first executes the query, then filters the results for what is visible to you.

You can try adding `LIMIT 100` to the end of these queries and see if the number of items returned increases.